# Screen orientation = "portrait" works on most devices but not on OnePlus 11 device with OxygenOS

Tags: android, kotlin

There are a lot questions about screen orientation. This one is a specific question for OxygenOS (on f.i. a OnePlus 11). Using:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

makes that rotation of the screen doesn't change the layout of the app. It works on 99% of the devices, but not for OxygenOS on f.i. a OnePlus 11.

I tried:

```
android:screenOrientation="locked"
```

and:

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

but somehow OxygenOS ingnores the above.

Does anyone recognize this issue and also has a solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that setting the screen orientation on the application level works for most devices:

```
<application
     android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

but not for all devices like an OnePlus 11. In that case you have to specify the screen orientation on every activity, like:

```
<activity
   android:name=".Help"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
/>
<activity
   android:name=".Info"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
/>
```